# Eclipse shows "Install local cloud services" on Boot Dashboard - how to get rid of this?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Eclipse shows an "Install local cloud services" option when listing the local services in the Boot Dashboard tab (see below). Is there a way to get rid of this?

When I click on it it wants to install a Spring Cloud CLI which I don't need. The right click context menu does not have anything that looks like it would allow to remove the option from the service list. Is there any setting that disables this option?
It's an annoying distraction.

[image: Annoying functionality]

Comment: Use the twisty to hide it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no option to hide that entry, but I agree that it definitely makes sense to add that. Please file an item at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/